# How to debug python .exe file (pyinstaller)

Tags: python-2.7, pyinstaller

I have been very happy with using the pyinstaller to make windows programs (.exe files]. But I find the debugging phase very time consuming.

I would like to pyinstaller to compile the python code so it will display the error if it crashes.

So far I have made a `try` and `except`

```
try:
    # My code goes here
except Exception as e:
    print "ERROR:"
    print type(e)     # the exception instance
    print e.args
```

But it is not giving me the full crash log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [`traceback`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/traceback.html) module, especially `print_...` functions. Also, try catching `BaseExceptions`, all exceptions are derived from it, and some aren't derived from `Exception`.